# how to add a disappearing pop up menu to a flatlist in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am a bit new to react native.

I'm trying to open a pop-up menu from a flat list

so if the user clicks on something like three dots at a corner of each list item a pop up appears with clickable options similar to the below images

Image 1- Initial state, before clicking the three dots on the right of each flatList item
[image: initial state, before clicking three dots]

Image 2- final state, afterclicking the three dots on the right of each flatList item
[image: final state after clicking the three dots]
Please advise me on how I can achieve this in react native

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use [react-native-material-menu](https://github.com/mxck/react-native-material-menu).

[image: showcase]

**Example code:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Menu, MenuItem, MenuDivider } from 'react-native-material-menu';

export default function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const hideMenu = () => setVisible(false);

  const showMenu = () => setVisible(true);

  return (
    <View style={{ height: '100%', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Menu
        visible={visible}
        anchor={<Text onPress={showMenu}>Show menu</Text>}
        onRequestClose={hideMenu}
      >
        <MenuItem onPress={hideMenu}>Menu item 1</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onPress={hideMenu}>Menu item 2</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem disabled>Disabled item</MenuItem>
        <MenuDivider />
        <MenuItem onPress={hideMenu}>Menu item 4</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </View>
  );
}
```